# openlaszlo Button and Radiogroup inerference

Tags: animation, openlaszlo

I am a openlaszlo beginner and I wnat to create an interactive web interface which simulates the indications of a vomplex astronomic clock. It should be possible to input e.g. the coodriantes and date/time or to select a realtime or timelapse modus.

I have tried to use a edittext field and button and a radiobutton group to select the informations and then to move an image according to the selsction. 
When I use only the edittext field and the button, then it works. The text entry is displayed in the output edittext field and the image really rotates the arc which was given. When I add the radiobutton group, then the selected arc is displayed in the output edittext field, but no rotation of the image occurs. Can someone help?

Here is the code

```
<canvas>
<!-- Load of the image -->
<view name="Zeiger" x="100" y="100" resource="images/Kal_Ring_Stundenzeiger.gif" id="HandID">
  <!-- Methode to rotate the image, Arc is set by the argument -->
  <method name="rotate" args="Arc">
      var increment = 0 + Arc;
  var dur = 700;
  this.animate('rotation',increment,dur);
  </method>
</view>

<!-- Control unit -->
<view name="Bedienung" x="200" y="10">
  <simplelayout axis="y" inset="8"/>  

  <text text="Output:"/>
  <edittext id="outputID" text = "0"/>     

  <text text="Arc:"/>
  <edittext id="WinkelID" text = "51"/>

  <button x="000" y="160"> 
    Rotation
    <!-- Handler to execute the Method  -->
    <handler name="onclick">
        var x = WinkelID.getText();
        HandID.rotate(x);
        outputID.setAttribute('text',x);
    </handler>
  </button>
  <!-- when I remove the radiogroup, then the image rotates -->
  <radiogroup id="group1ID">
    <handler name="onselect">
      var Arcchoice = this.getValue();
      HandID.rotate(Arcchoice);
      outputID.setAttribute('text',Arcchoice);
    </handler>
    <radiobutton value="0" text="0°" selected="true"/>
    <radiobutton value="90" text="90°"/>
    <radiobutton value="180" text="180°"/>
    <radiobutton value="270" text="270°"/>
    <radiobutton value="360" text="360°"/>
  </radiogroup>
</view>

</canvas>
```

Comment: Which OpenLaszlo version, runtime and browser are you using? Do you see the problem in all browsers and runtimes? The best OpenLaszlo version to use at the moment is 5.0 (trunk), since many bugs were fixed for 5.0, which have not been fixed in 4.9.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code with OpenLaszlo 5.0 trunk, and it works as expected in both the SWF10 and DHTML runtime.

Here is a screenshot of the app with a resource from the LzClock widget (didn't have your SWF resource available for testing). I've entered the arc value into the textfield and clicked the button to set the rotation.

[image]

I've tested with Chrome and Firefox on Linux, haven't tested with Windows.

Comment: Thank you Raju, I have used Lazlo 4.9.0 and after update to 5.0.X it is working at my windows 7 computer.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that so many bugs got fixed in 5.0, but that there has not been any official release for such a long time. Many people run into problems with 4.9, not knowing that it would be better to use 5.0.